# Eclipse GMF Dashboard: Generate diagram editor fails ("Problems while generating code")

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

Tried to follow this tutorial (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Modeling_Framework/Tutorial/Part_4) and to create an RCP Diagram Editor.
Everything works fine, until the last step "Generate diagram editor" fails with this error message:

> 'Executable Templates' has encountered a problem.
>
> Problems while generating code

...Details shows a bunch of:

> Exception (Boolean expected (was: org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl$1)!:in CodeStyle, line 18) while generating code
> Boolean expected (was: org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl$1)!:in CodeStyle, line 18
> Exception (Boolean expected (was: org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl$1)!:in CodeStyle, line 83) while generating code
> Boolean expected (was: org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl$1)!:in CodeStyle, line 83
> Exception (Boolean expected (was: org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl$1)!:in CodeStyle, line 18) while generating code
> Boolean expected (was: org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl$1)!:in CodeStyle, line 18
> Exception (Boolean expected (was: org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl$1)!:in CodeStyle, line 83) while generating code
> Boolean expected (was: org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl$1)!:in CodeStyle, line 83
> Exception (Boolean expected (was: org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl$1)!:in CodeStyle, line 89) while generating code
> Boolean expected (was: org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.internal.OCLStandardLibraryImpl$1)!:in CodeStyle, line 89

I am new to eclipse and GMF and have no clue what i might have overlooked and wrongly configured.
(I am using current Mars-Eclipse with the GMF-Stuff installed via "Help" > "Install new software")
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the genmodel set the compliance to 6.0.

more info [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/369075/)

Comment: That did work (but now i have to deal with conflicting dependencies ;D)